# yii2 hasOne relation work wrong

Tags: php, yii2

I have 2 tables : users and favorite the following :

[image: users table]

[image: favorite]

now I establish a relation between them like the following in Favorite model

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id', 'user_favorited']);
}
```

in Controller I find a list of user's favorites

```
public function actionGetList()
{
    $favorite = Favorite::find()->where([
              'user_favoriting' => Yii::$app->user->id
          ])->all();
    foreach ($favorite as $key => $item) {
        # code...
        echo "<pre>"; var_dump($item->user); echo "<br/>"; die('123');
    }
    return $favorite;
}
```

But when I make a request to this action I get an error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'\nThe SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`0`, `1`) IN ((12, 80))",
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#declaring-relations) you have to use:

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_favorited']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks your answer but it seems it's the same with relation I established in my question